# VB.Net Self Referencing

Tags: vb.net

How can an object reference itself?

I want to create a Menu Item where, when clicked, it navigates to its own title.

The following code is almost complete, but I just don't know what to use for `foo`.

```
ContextMenu2.MenuItems.Add(Browser.URL.OriginalURL, Browser.Navigate(foo.Text))
```

EDIT:  some context.

I'm trying to make a favorites system for my web browser. The ContextMenu is linked to a button (when the button is clicked, the Menu shows up.) So I would like the new MenuItem, when clicked, to navigate to its own title. The title is a URL.

```
Private Sub MenuItem6_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem6.Click
    ContextMenu2.MenuItems.Add(Browser.DocumentTitle, 
                               Browser.Navigate(foo.Text))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The keyword for referring to yourself in VB, is Me.  So `Me.Text`

EDIT: while the above is correct, your comment in response to Michael, indicates that you mean in the context of an event, specifically the event sender.  In which case you normally cast the sender to the appropriate type and use it, or simply use the item that you are handling the event for if there is only one.  In your example, MenuItem6.Text..

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred to comment, but I don't have the rep :)

Your question as stated feels a bit ambiguous to me, and the line of code you supplied doesn't help the matter. At first glance it would appear ContextMenu2.MenuItems is a dictionary of some T, but OriginalURL doesn't seem like a logical key entry.

If you pass 'me.Text' as an argument to Browser.Navigate, you will be passing the property 'Text' of whatever class is performing the call on ContextMenu2. I don't believe that is your intention.

Can you please clarify your question? Some additional context for the objects and methods would help.

Comment: I'm trying to make a favorites system for my web browser. The `ContextMenu` is linked to a button (when the button is clicked, the Menu shows up.) So I would like the new `MenuItem`, when clicked, to navigate to its own title. The title is a URL. `Private Sub MenuItem6_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem6.Click
        ContextMenu2.MenuItems.Add(Browser.DocumentTitle, Browser.Navigate(foo.Text))
    End Sub`  Also if you have any suggestions or an easier way to do this I am open to suggestions.

Comment: @Michael: +1 for an excellent question.  I had assumed that "foo" was a form or some other control where it made sense, but you elicited just the information needed to put the question in context.